# Unity SteamVR teleportation on moving teleportation area

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamvr

I have the ship in my Unity VR scene, that moves in space via the animation with animator component on it. Also on this ship I have a teleportation area and player, that are parented to ship prefab, so they are moving with it.

When I try to teleport my player at some point on teleportation area, I have an issue that at the time of frame update teleportation area moves a little and player appears a little behind from teleportation area.

I drawn a little [scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySFkv.png), that illustrate my problem. The top part of this scheme is my start situation, when player wants to teleport to red point. And the bottom part is the situation after teleportation: the ship with teleportation area moves forward, and player appears on red point, neither green.

Maybe someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if someone will face this problem, here is my solituion: the idea is really simple, just add difference in teleportation area postions in time to player position after teleportation.
So in teleport.cs, I saved teleportation object, and it's postition before teleportation and after player teleportation, i added such code:

```
teleportObjectPositionAfterTeleportation = teleportObject.transform.position;
diffInPositions = teleportObjectPositionAfterTeleportation - teleportObjectPositionBeforeTeleportation;
player.trackingOriginTransform.position += diffInPositions;
```